# Problems with SDL image

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm running on a mac OS 10.8.2 and compiling my program with the following command;

```
g++ main.cpp `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -o whateverfilename
```

I can compile SDL programs just fine but as soon as I try to use the SDL image library, things go wrong - I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_IMG_Init", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in cco8lzYA.o
  "_IMG_Load_RW", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in cco8lzYA.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm guessing the linker is missing a search path or something. I've been trying to look up and edit the linker search paths but can't seem to manage even that so if someone could tell me how to do that or what other problems I might be causing I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to add the `lSDL_Image` compiler flag, I'm very much a noob when it comes to C++ and SDL, it was ages since I've done anything with it.

I also very much recommend [LazyFoo's tutorials](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/index.php)

Comment: Had tried it before but had the flag wrong, was using "SDL_image" without the "l". Works now, thanks!